# casperjs fails to generate image via php's shell exec

Tags: php, shell, phantomjs, casperjs

When I run the casper script via ubuntu terminal it captures the website(generates img as it is supposed to)  but when i feed that command to php's shell exec it fails to generate the img. Any genereal problem ?

Comment: Please update your question with more information. Without knowing much, I would ask you check the permissions PHP runs under and if it can write to the file/directory.

Comment: hello did you find the solution if yes then please post your code. cause I am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue not ten minutes ago!! For me the issue was permissions. I solved it with the following command:

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ./

however I DON'T recommend you run that willy nilly, I've seriously screwed up my server in the past playing about with permissions!